# Set dynamic height of tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I have one tableview in my screen. I want to show that tableview in max that height only but I want to set its height according to row. If there is two row then it height should be up to two row. Other part of table view should not be shown.

[image]

You can see right now there is two row only but table height is more so it is showing that part.I want to set table height dynamically. I dont know how to set. I also google it but though I dont find any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the number of row first and then multiply it by height of individual row.

```
float height = (no_of_row) * row_height + header_height; // 4*25.00 + 10

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.table.frame.origin.x, self.table.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, height);

self.table.frame =frame;
```

Comment: and If I have header in table then will it added to this formula or not?

Comment: Yes then add the height of the header as well. But it depends how many section are there. If there is more than one then multiply it with number of section and then add.

Comment: can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133870/last-row-not-fit-in-dynamic-height

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this : 
a UITableView whose height = Screen height - Navigationbar height. 
i-e

> height = self.view.frame.size.height-64

```
self.dataArrayForCategory is our Datasource and 44 is our RowHeight.
```

> ```
> [self.tblHomeMenu setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,
> 44*self.dataArrayForCategory.count)];
> (self.tblHomeMenu.frame.size.height>height)?[self.tblHomeMenu
> setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,
> height)]:[self.tblHomeMenu
> setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44*self.dataArrayForCategory.count)];
> if (self.tblHomeMenu.frame.size.height>self.view.frame.size.height-64)
> {
>     [self.tblHomeMenu setScrollEnabled:YES];
> }
> ```

I had a UITableView whose height is Screensize - Navigationbar.

last line is used if UITableView height > Screensize - Navigationbar then UITableView should be scrollable else it should not.

in your case your height will be height of your UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
float height=27.0f*[yourArray count];
if (height > MaxHeight)
{
    height = MaxHeight;
}

[yourTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(yourTableView.frame.origin.x, yourTableView.frame.origin.y,yourWidth,height)];
```

Comment: What is 27? :-) Magic numbers are very bad